# Undo and Redo on Macbook not functioning

Tags: shortcut, osx

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> combinations are essentially ignored on my Macbook. It's behaving like an unqualified <kbd>Z</kbd> key press.  How do I get that to work on Macbook or is there another means of performing undo/redo?

Comment: I'm locking this post, because while it has some useful information, it does not directly relate to Blender in any way.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac OS X the keyboard shortcuts for undo and redo are <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, consistent with other applications on this operating system.